# Why Rmarkdown file cannot be knitted to HTML

Tags: r, r-markdown

I created RMarkdown file to knit to HTML file. then Saved it in Rmd. format in a folder. When I try to press the button `knit to HTML`, nothing happened. I assume that Rstudio session starts lagging (not sure), because when I try to run `1+1` it gives no output in the console.
I found somewhere that this may happen if MikTex is not downloaded, but I downloaded and the same error appears. Do you know where the problem can come from?

Comment: Could you provide a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) of your .Rmd code?

Comment: Please post your code so we can see where something may be wrong.